# Combining Two Condition Sets by OR,AND operators in Google Analytics Data Query Filter

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to combine two separate sets of conditions,like (A) OR (B AND c AND d) in Google Analytics Data Query Filter This is what i want

**exclude all visits:**

```
*coming from the US*
```

**OR**

```
*`coming from source=xyz AND medium=pqr AND keyword contaning 'abc'`*
```

i am currently tyring to use this query but it's not working

*`"a:country!=United States,ga:source!=xyz;ga:medium!=pqr;ga:keyword!=abc"`*

please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this just set the segment and filter criteria as follow

```
segment = dynamic::ga:country!=United States
```

and

```
filter = ga:source!=xyz,ga:medium!=pqr,ga:keyword!=key1;ga:keyword!=key2
```

that's work for me thank you all